# Chrome developer tools: constant "page unresponsive" messages

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools

When I open a separate Chrome developer tools window in order to look at a page's JavaScript code I get this window in regular intervals:

[image]

When I click "wait" the window goes away but comes back soon after.

**How can I get rid of this annoying message?**

This happens on Chrome 32 on Windows, and on different websites (e.g. http://spiegel.de).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it does seem that the issue is with the 32.0.1700.102 version of Google Chrome.

I've got several users who are experiencing the problem. It only seems to happen when you are working with sites that open popups (the kind you want) such as opening and email in a new window in Google Mail.

Its seams like the latest update may have helped fix the issue(32.0.1700.102 m), or some users are reporting that the v33 beta does not have the issue. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/1PgURxP9_-k/It9TupoPEgQJ

Bug report here:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=335248

Comment: It does seem to be fixed in 32.0.1700.102. Thanks!